# NFC UID Keyboard Emulator / Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, nfc

I am trying to get UID from NFC tag using Android 4.4 using phonegap and phonegap-nfc-master plugin. That return me an hexadecimal string.
But when I read the same tag with an Usb Nfc keyboard emulator (like this: http://www.shopnfc.it/gb/nfc-readers-writers/40-usb-nfc-loginer-keyboard-emulator.html) the results is a decimal number. Ok. Now I'am trying to convert dec to hex but the codes do not match.
Can you help me please?
Thanks

**EDIT:**
For example, Android returns ID 04a9dba2853280 and Keyboard Emulator returns 3685287048 for the same tag. I tried to convert hexadecimal by removing some character but doesn't. I don't understand the logic of this conversion. That Id is unique and I think there is only a conversion problem.

Comment: What decimal number do you get and what UID do you read from the same tag with Android?

Comment: For example, Android returns ID 04a9dba2853280 and Keyboard Emulator returns 3685287048 for the same tag. I tried to convert hexadecimal by removing some character but doesn't. I don't understand the logic of this conversion. That Id is unique and I think there is only a conversion problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decimal number you receive (3685287048) is `DBA90488` in hexadecimal representation. Thus, the keyboard-emulation reader gives you the first cascade-level part of the tag UID (see ISO/IEC 14443-3 for reference).

For a tag with a 7-byte UID `zzyyxxwwvvuutt` (in your case `04A9DBA2853280`), the ISO 14443-3 anti-collision has to cascade levels. The UID in cascase-level 1 is `88zzyyxx` (in your case `8804A9DB`). `88` is the cascade tag which is used to distinguish (i.e. produce collissions between) 4-byte UIDs (which use only a single cascade-level) and tags with longer UIDs (7/10-byte). The UID part in cascade-level 2 is then `wwvvuutt` (in your case `A2853280`).

As your reader stops the enumeration procedure after cascade-level 1, it detects only the first part of the UID (including the cascade tag): `88zzyyxx`. This translates to the decimal number:

```
xx_h * 2^24 + yy_h * 2^16 + zz_h * 2^8 + 88_h
```

In your case:

```
DB_h * 2^24 + A9_h * 2^16 + 04_h * 2^8 + 88_h = 
 219 * 2^24 +  169 * 2^16 +    4 * 2^8 +  136 = 
 3674210304 +    11075584 +       1024 +  136 = 
                                   3685287048
```

Comment: Thank you! Very exhaustive. But in this case it would be impossible to transform 3685287048 into 04A9DBA2853280

Comment: Correct, as I wrote above: your keyboard-emulation reader stops after cascade-level 1, so the remaining part of the UID is inaccessible through that reader (unless there is any configuration options to activate this...). Effectively, this means that you only see the first three bytes of the UID if you use that reader.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I can solve this by transform hexadeciman Android's code to keyboard-emulation's decimal. In this case I can compare values. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The reader that you had bought is designed for Mifare chips, now there is a loginer for all tags, with hexadecimal

http://www.shopnfc.it/en/nfc-readers-writers/61-nfc-loginer.html

It can easily read the NFC Tag's Unique ID (UID) and automatically writes it where the cursor is positioned on the display, and "press" enter, too. For this reason, it can be used to make a quick and safe access to PC/mobile/tablet.